# Test Class - Unable to select a picklist value from field having reference to Global Picklist

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I am trying to create an object's instance in a test class. While assigning some value to a picklist field which gets its value from a global picklist, I get this error:

> bad value for restricted picklist: `<value_that_i_provide>`.

Comment: Some times, certain picklist entries are restricted by RecordType.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the available values for a picklist from its describe:

```
DescribeFieldResult describe = MyObject__c.PicklistField__c.getDescribe();
List<PicklistEntry> availableValues = describe.getPicklistValues();
```

If you want to arbitrarily select one, you  can pull its value:

```
MyObject__c testRecord = new MyObject__c(PicklistField__c = availableValues[0].getValue());
```

Of course this can all be one-lined if you desire:

```
testRecord.PicklistField__c = MyObject__c.PicklistField__c.getDescribe()
    .getPicklistValues()[0].getValue();
```

Comment: Hi, we have used global picklist set, and unfortunately, it does not resolve the issue. It throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use something like this for my test classes if I want to add a picklist value.
Let's say I have a piclklist field with the name **Department__c** on my **Contact** object. When testing I use this:

```
Department__c =SObjectType.Contact.Fields.Department__c.PicklistValues[0].getValue();
```

This normally helps and it is one line of code only.

Regards.

Comment: Hi, we have used global picklist set, and unfortunately, it does not resolve the issue. It throws the same error.